# How does a binary search work if the searched value is not found?

Tags: binary-search

How does a binary search work if the searched value is not found?

for example if you were to search for 60 in this array:

```
ANDMarks = {1, 6, 38, 39, 45, 55, 57, 61, 72, 73, 88, 96}
```

How does it end? I have dry run the code up until the search is at the indexes 6 and 7. To make it easier to get what I'm asking, here is my dry run:

Steps:

1.Find the middle value.

```
Middle value = (index of 1st element + index of last element)/2
Middle value = (0+11)/2
Middle value = 5 
Middle value = element in 5th index => 55

Indexes     0   1   2   3   4   **5**   6   7   8   9   10  11
Elements    1   6   38  39  45  **55**  57  61  72  73  88  96
```

Step 2. Middle value(55) != 60

Step 3. Middle value < Searched valued (55 < 60)

Consider the part of the array that is after the middle value

```
Indexes     6   7   8   9   10  11
Elements    57  61  72  73  88  96
```

Step 4.

```
Middle value = (index of 1st element + index of last element)/2
Middle value = (6+11)/2
Middle value = 8
Middle value = element in 8th index => 72

Indexes     6   7   **8**   9   10  11
Elements    57  61  **72**  73  88  96
```

Step 5. Middle value(72) != 60

Step 6. Middle value > Searched value (72 > 60)

Consider the part of the array that is before the middle value.

```
Indexes     6   7
Elements    57  61
```

Now what happens?

Answer (score 3):

I understand I am bit late here and probably you have figured it out by now but nonetheless, this question has over 5k views and no clear explanation.

May be my explanation can help any aspiring computer science enthusiast.

[Here is my explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c28U.png) At the moment, I do not have enough reputation on stack overflow so it won't allow me embed an image. Please feel free, to check the explanation as it contains an image.

If anybody likes or agrees, do please feel free to leave a thumbs up as it would encourage me to leave more responses and posts on Stack Overflow.

Below is my JavaScript code, you may copy paste in Chrome Developer tools, debug it and see how it works.

```js
function binarySearch(arr, val) {
  let mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  let left = 0;
  let right = arr.length - 1;
  while (arr[mid] !== val && ((left != mid) && (mid != right))) {
    if (val > arr[mid]) {
      left = mid + 1;
      mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
    } else if (val < arr[mid]) {
      right = mid - 1;
      mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
    }
  }
  return arr[mid] === val ? mid : -1;
}

arr1 = [3, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 20]
console.log(binarySearch(arr1, 14));
console.log(binarySearch(arr1, 1));
console.log(binarySearch(arr1, 23));
console.log(binarySearch(arr1, 8));
console.log(binarySearch(arr1, 16));
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Step 7.

```
Middle value = (index of 1st element + index of last element)/2
Middle value = (6+7)/2
Middle value = 6
Middle value = element in 8th index => 57

Indexes     **6**   7
Elements    **57**  61
```

Step 8. Middle value(57) != 60

Step 9. Middle value < Searched value (57 < 60)

Consider the part of the array that is after the middle value.

```
Indexes     7
Elements    61
```

Step 10.

```
Middle value = (index of 1st element + index of last element)/2
Middle value = (7+7)/2
Middle value = 7
Middle value = element in 8th index => 61
```

Step 11. Middle value != 60

Step 12. Value not found, end of execution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void binarySearch(int value)
{
    int low=0;
    int high=actualSize-1;
    boolean foundStatus=false;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid = (low+high) / 2;
        if(initArray[mid]>value)
        {
            high=mid-1;
        }
        else if(initArray[mid]<value)
        {
            low=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element found at index:"+mid);
            low=high+1;
            foundStatus=true;
        }
    }
    if(!foundStatus)
        System.out.println("Element not found");
}
```